# How to correctly use Postfix virtual aliases?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, mail-server, email-server

All emails sent to my email server arrive in the inbox of `root`, regardless of the `user` specified in `user@domain.com`.

My virtual file in `/etc/postfix/virtual` is:

```
query1@domain1.com username1
query1@domain2.com root
```

and my postfix `main.cf` file contains

```
myhostname = domain1.com
mydestination = domain1.com, domain2.com
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_domains = domain1.com domain2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

With my current understanding, incoming mail to `query1@domain1.com` will be checked against `virtual_alias_domains`. As `domain1.com` is listed, the `virtual` file will be checked. Here, the entire address `query1@domain1.com` is mapped to the account `username1`, and mail is placed in the Maildir of the UNIX account with name `username1`.

I'm thinking I might have misunderstood how `virtual_domains` work in this context - if so, could someone please explain what I have misunderstood ?

Otherwise, if my understanding is correct, why would mail not be reaching the intended user, and being delivered to the `root` user instead ?

### Environment Specs

I am running Ubuntu with Postfix.